# How to check the facebook application permission for specific user through graph api in rails?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-3.1, koala

I want to check whether the user has give publish_stream permission to my application or not. If not want to get publish_stream permission.

Answer (score 22):

if you are using the Koala Gem just use:

```
#check wether wallpost is allowed
permissions = graph.get_connections('me','permissions')
@has_wallpost_permission = permissions.select{|o| o['permission'] == 'manage_pages'}.length == 1
```

Comment: That's half of it but how do you tell Koala to request certain permissions from the user when they authorise the app?

Answer (score 0):

You must autorize user with publish_stream permission. 
In rails I do it with [OmniAuth gem](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth).

My post can help you - [Publish stream in Facebook & Twitter with OmniAuth](http://superp.tumblr.com/post/4109090091/publish-stream-in-facebook-twitter-with-omniauth)

Comment: The scenario is the user has authorize the app. I want to check if the  user given certain permission to my app. if not I want to take that permission. Is this possible in facebook graph API or in rails 3. My app is running in facebook canvas.

Comment: You can use FQL query to [check permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Koala you can send request 'GET /{user-id}/permissions'
This is described in 'Checking Current Permissions' section here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1